# slide image from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

can't seem to find a  solution to this. I would like to create a jQuery image slider.I need to dynamically load images stored on my MYSQL database .  Any suggestions?

Comment: If they have a primary id index, then you could just get them with a `$.post` to a PHP file that gets the files using a query like `SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: this isn't really a javascript question.  Jquery has plenty of methods for animation, but you want to know how to access the most recent images that you are storing in your database.  We need to know how where you are storing the images, what database, and what framework/method of connecting to the database.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to note here is that Javascript/jQuery alone cannot do what you are asking. Pulling anything from a database is a *server* function and must be run using some form of server code. Javascript and jQuery are both client-side languages that run after the page has loaded, but while they are relevant to this answer, they are not the only thing that is required.

For this example I will be using PHP.

### Your jQuery

Your jQuery has to load information that will be generated from a PHP file, so in order to do that, we will use a post function with a callback that places the retrieved data into the slider.

```
$.post("/php/script.php", function(data){
    $(".slider").html(data);
});
```

### PHP

I assume you are using a MySQL database structure similar to the following, where you have an auto-incremented primary index. Without a unique number (Ascending) for each image you add, this problem becomes quite difficult.

```
id---|---URL---
---------------
1    | path to image 1
2    | path to image 2
etc.
```

I will not write all of this for you, but the main statement you will need to retrieve the URLs from the database is this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3
```

This will get the three most recent URLs from your database. Then in your fetch function:

```
echo '<img src="'.$array["URL"].'">';
```

You simply have to echo out the object with the retrieved URLs. Then initialize your slider and you'll be good to go.

Comment: iam using wowslider to slide the images

Comment: <div id="wowslider-container1">
 <div class="ws_images"><ul>
<li><img src=""/></li>       <?php 
         include 'connection.php';
         $query="SELECT path FROM `sliderimage` ";
         $result=mysql_query($query);
         while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
          echo "<li ><a href= view_slider_image.php";
          echo '<img src="'.$array["path"].'">';
          echo " </a></li> <br/>";
         }
        ?> 
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets">
  <div></div>

Comment: where i refer the image reference to wowslider

Comment: @febeena incredible... David went out of his way to give an *incredibly* detailed answer and you expect him to do all the work for you. Please show some effort and give credit where credit is due. +1 David. Nicely done, sir.